# Refactoring if elsif else in Ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement

Is there a way to refactor this code and make it cleaner? Can you use fewer booleans to solve this problem?

```
def get_grade(grade_num)
  if grade_num > 100
    return "Please enter a number between 0 and 100"
  elsif grade_num <=100 && grade_num >= 90
    return 'A'
  elsif grade_num < 90 && grade_num >= 80
    return 'B'
  elsif grade_num < 80 && grade_num >= 70
    return 'C'
  elsif grade_num < 70 && grade_num >= 60
    return 'D'
  elsif grade_num < 60
    return 'F'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about using `Range` and a `case` statement?

```
def get_grade(grade)
  case grade
  when 90..100 then 'A'
  when 80...90 then 'B'
  when 70...80 then 'C'
  when 60...70 then 'D'
  when  0...60 then 'F'
  else      
    'Please enter a number between 0 and 100'
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah. Sadly nobody uses `between? `. I like `grade.between?(1, 100)` better than `(1..100).cover?(grade)`

Comment: @steenslag: TIL `between` is much better. Thank you.

Comment: If 0 through 100 are acceptable values, wouldn't you want the min/max to be `grade.between?(0, 100)`?  Also, the values 90, 80, and 70 would be true in two of the four cases listed.  Probably want those ranges to be `80...89`, `70...79`, and `50...69`.

Comment: You've always been a softie. While the OP has set the threshold for passing at 60, you've bumped it down to 50. I prefer `cover?`, as someone unfamiliar with `between?` (like myself) may not know if it's inclusive or exclusive of end points, whereas (to me) `cover?` sounds inclusive.

Comment: @digijim: A range with three dots like `80...90` excludes the last element.

Comment: I would do `when 0...60 then 'F'; else "Please enter ...`.

Comment: You put `E` instead of `F`. And don't forget `def`.

Answer (score 3):

For large classes, where efficiency is paramount:

```
GRADES = {
  ( 0...60) => "Fail",
  (60...70) => "D",
  (70...80) => "C",
  (80...90) => "B",
  (90..100) => "A" }

TO_MARK = GRADES.flat_map { |r,mark| r.to_a.product([mark]) }.to_h
  #=> {0=>"Fail", 1=>"Fail",..., 59=>"Fail", 60=>"D",..., 69=>"D",
  #    70=>"C",..., 79=>"C", 80=>"B",..., 89=>"B", 90=>"A",..., 100=>"A"} 

TO_MARK[33] #=> "Fail" 
TO_MARK[65] #=> "D" 
TO_MARK[80] #=> "B" 
TO_MARK[90] #=> "A"
```